# How to get the starting address of each PE section in C?

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

Is it possible to write a C code that retrieve its PE sections addresses after compiling it to `.exe` ?

Comment: Couldn't you just read the `.exe` file from within that very program?

Comment: Yes. You should begin by studying the PE format.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean you want to access each section of exe ?
If yes, then find below way to do so:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    LPCSTR fileName="inputFile.exe";
    HANDLE hFile;
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileBase;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFile failed \n");
        return 1;
    }

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

    if(hFileMapping==0)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

    if(lpFileBase==0)
    {
        printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;
    if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched \n");

        peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);
        if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");
            //once found valid exe or dll

            //go to first section
            sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
            UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

            //No of sections
            printf("\n No of sections : %d \n",nSectionCount);

            //sectionHeader contains address of first section
            //traverse each section by below way
            for( UINT i=0; i<nSectionCount; ++i, ++sectionHeader )
            {
                //section information
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient & easier to just read the sections from it's own memory instead of reading it from disk

Comment: If you want virtual address refer this function                                            [ImageRvaToVa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680218(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @9090 since you're trying to read your own process's sections, you can get the image base address using GetModuleHandle(NULL). You can directly cast that address to PIMAGE_DOS_HEADERS. Read everything from there. PS: Tag me next time, otherwise I don't get a notification.